# first character truncated when committing hgsub

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to create a mercurial repository containing subrepositores. I have the following entry in my .hgsub file:

```
subrepo1 = http://hgserver.domain.com/subrepo1
```

However, when committing, I get the following message:

```
B:\>hg commit
committing subrepository ubrepo1
```

Why is the first character removed?

Comment: What is the encoding of that hgsub file?

Comment: I have tried both UTF-8 without BOM and ANSI in both Windows and UNIX formats. I have used Notepad++ for the conversions. Unfortunately, the problem persists.

Comment: When I try UTF-8, I get the following: committing subrepository ╗┐subrepo1, which is no real improvement...

Comment: Then I don't know, I have never experienced that. Could you zip up the file with the problem, ie. the .hgsub file, and post it somewhere? If not online, to my email? lasse@vkarlsen.no, I'd sure like to take a look at it. Of course, edit out any pertinent secrets  first :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It seems the problem is a bug and has already been fixed now (see answer below).

Answer (score 6):

This is clearly a bug.

But StackOverflow is **not** the Mercurial bugtracker, and the best you can hope for here is a workaround. You should instead report the issue to the Mercurial BTS, which the developers actually read, and which may result in someone actually fixing the bug:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BugTracker

But today is your lucky day: the Mercurial project leader happened to follow a link to Stack Overflow, got annoyed that people were reporting bugs in a place that doesn't ever make it to his inbox and weren't promptly getting redirected to the right place, so he filed a proper bug report, then fixed the bug:

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue3033

Turns out this particular bug is caused by the highly unusual pattern of committing to a repo at the root of the drive on a Windows machine with a subrepo. It's harmless and the fix will be in the next release on Nov 1.

Comment: My lucky day, indeed! Thanks so much for looking into this and fixing it so quickly. I will keep in mind to post these kind of queries on more relevant places in the future.